# Acessar chave direta

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Gostaria de acessar a chave direta de um objeto array sem precisar fazer um loop (foreach)

Ao invés de ser assim:

```
    $nome = "";
    $codigo   = 0;
    $objeto  = DB::select( "SELECT NOME FROM TABELA WHERE CODIGO = ?", array( $codigo ) );
    foreach ( $objeto as $obj ){
        $nome = $obj->nome;
    }
    echo $nome;
```

Gostaria que eu não precisasse de `foreach`

Tipo

```
   $nome = $objeto->nome;
```

Mas dá a seguinte mensagem:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua query esta errada:

```
SELECT NOME WHERE ID = ?
```

Falta `FROM [NOME DA TABELA AQUI]`, deveria ser assim:

```
DB::select( "SELECT NOME FROM minhatabela WHERE ID = ?", $nome );
```

E só pra constar, eu não faço ideia se a variável `$nome` é um array ou uma string, mas acaso **seja string** você deve passar assim:

```
DB::select('SELECT NOME FROM minhatabela WHERE ID = ?', [ $nome ]);
```

**[editado]**

Sua query esta errada ainda:

```
SELECT CODIGO FROM TABELA WHERE ID=?
```

No SELECT você só pede a coluna CODIGO, mas você quer o objeto `->nome`, logo é necessário selecionar ele também, assim:

```
SELECT codigo, nome FROM TABELA WHERE ID=?
```

Pra não precisar usar o `foreach` como só vai trazer um resultado pode usar assim:

```
$objeto = DB::select( "SELECT NOME FROM minhatabela WHERE ID = ?", [ $nome ])->first();

echo $objeto[0]->nome;
```

Comment: Blz. Muito obrigado, já me ajudou muito e já economizou umas linhas de codigo rsrs

Answer (score 0):

Quando tu faz uma consulta ele te retorna um array, se tu não passar por um foreach ele não vai trazer os atributos. Que no caso attributes é um índice desse array!

Comment: Pois é. Já que ele retorna um array eu gostaria de acessar o indice direto

Comment: Utilize o find na consulta. Assim retornará só um registro, e tu poderá acessar sem utilizar o foreach.