# Como acessar a propriedade em um objeto em PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Quando dei esse comando echo $user->cards apareceu isso:

```
[{"id":10,"id_user":2,"id_card":"11222","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"deleted_at":null}]
```

Como acessar a propriedade 'deleted_at' desse objeto ?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Acessar chave direta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249995/acessar-chave-direta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao usar o json_decode, a string gera um object dentro de um array.
Veja abaixo como proceder:

```
$str = '[{"id":10,"id_user":2,"id_card":"11222","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"deleted_at":null}]';
   $arr = json_decode($str);
   $deleted_at = $arr[0]->deleted_at;

   if (is_null($deleted_at)) {
      echo 'Nulo';
   } else {
      echo 'Não nulo';
   }
```

Isso irá exibir "Nulo".